Document history?
I'm new here, and looking for where can I find some older version of the official document on raspberrypi.com, or where to get the document history?
Specifically, for this document, at around May of 2023:
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html
Thanks!

On the corresponding github page, there is a "History" link on the right side near the top.  If you click through, there are only four commits after May 2023, and the one before that is Feb 2022.  If you click through the Feb/22 commit link, there is a diff shown with the changes made and in the bar above far right a "..." style menu button.  In there you will find "View file", which takes you to the corresponding version of the document:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/asciidoc/computers/linux_kernel/about-kernel.adoc

If there's an underlying github page like there is in this case, that's the better choice (see @goldilocks' answer).
However, if there's not, you can always use the Internet Archive "wayback machine".
Here's the link for your page, for May 2023 as you asked: https://web.archive.org/web/20230510083854/https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html
You can change the date in the top header, to see other versions.
